# Pygame image loading not working

Tags: pygame, python-3.6

All I do is try to load an image into pygame normally and get this:

```
imgst = pygame.image.load("start.jpg")
```

I try to run that but get this error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open start.jpg
```

Also I'm not able to load any images in pygame, it worked before but now it's just broke for some reason.

Comment: Is your program in the same folder as start.jpg? Are you running the Python program from that same folder?

Comment: @numbermaniac Yes and I am running it from the command prompt.

Comment: can we see a picture of your folder structure, and I there is more errors, can you show us

Comment: @SiddharthNand All I had to do was reinstall pygame, so now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so all I had to do was reinstall pygame(not sure why it stopped working) I used:

```
pip uninstall pygame
```

to uninstall pygame and:

```
pip install pygame
```

to reinstall pygame.